# Where does grep -r search by default?

Tags: grep, recursive

I found if I search using grep without specifying a path, like `grep -r 'mytext'` it takes infinitely long. Meanwhile if I search with path specified `grep -r 'mytext' .` it instantly finds what I need. So, I'm curious, in first form, in which directory does grep search?

UDATE: grep version: grep (GNU grep) 2.10

Comment: Try typing away, write `foomytextbar` (followed by Enter) after running `grep -r 'mytext'`.

Comment: amazing! So it looks like grep is waiting for a text to search in!

Comment: Indeed.  Many UNIX utilities *default to standard input* if there's no file argument (others use `-` to indicate stdin/out).

Comment: Eh, seems that's actually what is written in grep help: "Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input." That my inability to read manuals carefully. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Maybe you should specify what king of `grep` is that. With the GNU `grep` I use on Linux `grep -r 'mytext'` and `grep -r 'mytext' .` does the same thing: search recursively starting from the current directory. When the `-r` switch is used GNU `grep` _not_ searches STDIN.

Comment: @manatwork did you actually try it?

Comment: Yes @Mikel, I tried it. Even if you run `echo 'mytext' | grep -r 'mytext'`, `grep` will do a recursive search, as instructed by the `-r` switch.

Comment: So it doesn't print `mytext`?  With GNU grep 2.9 on Fedora 16, it acts like there is no `-r` and reads from stdin.

Comment: Ah. I tested with `grep` 2.12: http://pastebin.com/L4my26QS In meantime I found this in the NEWS file regarding version 2.11 (2012-03-02): "If no file operand is given, and a command-line -r or equivalent option is given, grep now searches the working directory.  Formerly grep ignored the -r and searched standard input nonrecursively. An -r found in GREP_OPTIONS does not have this new effect."

Comment: GNU grep recently changed behavior with -r argument (see [the commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=faf6ea13b3281a2004f5bfd1487708d1ba50a6c5)). So "grep -r PATTERN" with newer grep will search current directory and not STDIN.

Comment: @hluk Thanks for investigating.  Why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @gasan can you add the version of grep to your question (e.g. first line of  `grep --version`) :-)

Comment: @Mikel, i updated my question with a grep version. It seems that answer I pointed as correct is indeed a correct, because I'm using an 'old' grep. So it doesn't matter do I specify -r or not, if no directory is provided, it searches in STDIN. Btw, thanks for that investigation, now, I'll be aware of future changes in grep ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually it doesn't search anywhere. It waits for input from standard input.

Try this:

```
beast:~ viroos$ grep foo
```

when you type line containing "foo" and hit enter this line will be repeated otherwise cursor will be moved to new line but grep won't print anything.

Comment: As I commented above `grep -r PATTERN` with newer version of GNU grep will not read standard input but search for pattern in current directory (see [the commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=faf6ea13b3281a2004f5bfd1487708d1ba50a6c5)). This change makes sense since you probably don't want to search standard input when you specify `-r` flag.

Comment: I checked my grep version, it's 2.10, so this answer is perfectly relevant. Btw, now, i'll know what to wait from newer versions of grep.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as the previous answer by Maciek says:

> Actually it doesn't search anywhere. It waits for input from standard input.

However you can write into the stdin of an already running program if you have /proc available by piping data into it's 0th first descriptor:

In one terminal run

```
grep "hello"
```

and see it wait indefinitely...In another terminal type this:

```
echo "hello $USER" > /proc/`pgrep grep`/fd/0
```

see the first terminal print hello and your username.