# Using Grep Command Without Specifying a Certain Directory

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find

Can you use the `grep` command without specifying a directory path afterwards?

Example:

```
$ sudo grep "filename" /
```

I have also tried this:

```
 sudo find / -type f grep -l "filename"
```

Still no luck.

Basically I am searching for where the `LoadModule` is specified in the Apache2 Config file. I thought it was in here: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but it isn't.

Comment: `grep -ri LoadModule /etc/apache2/*` ; the question is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it as clear as possible though

Comment: In the future try to separate different doubts in different questions. I can see clearly here one about grep usage, and other about Apache. Cheers.

Comment: `-type grep` ? Maybe look in the man page at what the flags you are using do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does grep -r search by default?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38793/where-does-grep-r-search-by-default)

Comment: @123 whoops, yeah that one had an error, I will update it with what I had before I tried that one :)

Comment: try grep -irp "SearchString" /*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep expects you to give it a filename, or a list of filenames. It doesn't take a path as argument. Thus, your first attempt could have been written as

```
sudo grep searchstring /*
```

to search for all files immediately under the root. (Which is probably not what you want.)

**Edit:** GNU grep actually can search recursively, so you could do

```
sudo grep -r searchstring /
```

In the second instance, you've misunderstood how find works. `-type` requires an argument telling it what type of file to look for, and just adding "grep" afterwards does nothing. You can, however, tell it to execute a command on each file it finds, and that's probably what you were looking for. Like so:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -l searchstring {} \;
```

The `{}` means "the name of the file", and `\;` means "the command is done now".

Comment: *GNU* grep has a nice `--recursive` (or `-r`) option. Try `grep -r 'nomefile' /`

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I am the root user, so using option 1 is what I wanted to do. This is a test Virtual Machine, so its only me that uses this machine. @andcoz, that is looking promising, its running now.

Comment: right @andcoz, I'd completely forgotten that. I'm too old; I started using grep on Solaris, which didn't have that, so I learned to use find instead and it's stuck with me.

Comment: Find...exec ... + is a good alternative here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Jenny's answer is the most general one. You should be able to find what you need with

```
grep -r -i '^[[:space:]]*LoadModule' /etc/apache2
```

To be pedantic, you should also grep for and note any 'include' directives which lie outside the apache2 directory structure.

For that, you could try to get the list of files that `apache2ctl -t` opens to check the configuration with something like:

```
APACHE_HTTPD='ltrace -s4096 -e open@libapr* apache2' apache2ctl -t 2>&1 |
  cut -d\" -sf2 |
  grep -v /dev/ |
  sort -u |
  xargs -rd '\n' grep -i '^[[:space:]]*LoadModule'
```